# gin nodejs is there a way to use the forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a task scheduler with nodejs but my program does not read my `forEach` loop in the run function.

```
 run: function(req, res, callback){
        // req and res are the express request and response objects

        // set timestamp for when cron is invoked
        var now = Date.now();

        // set up array to contain cron tasks that are ready to execute
        var scheduledTasks = [];

       _.forEach(cronRecord, function(taskDefinition, taskN//console.log("this is to show on run");
            // check if the task is due
            if(taskDefinition.lastrun === null || _checkIfTaskIsDue(taskDefinition, now)){
                scheduledTasks.push(
                    function(asyncCallback){
                        taskDefinition.task(asyncCallback);
                    }
                );
            }
        });


        // if there are tasks due, run them
        if(scheduledTasks.length > 0){
            async.parallel(scheduledTasks, function(err){
                // cron tasks will have run
                console.log(err);
                return;
            });
        } else {
            // no cron tasks are due
            return callback(null);
        }

        // function to check if a cron task is due to be executed
        // returns true if the cron task is due, returns false otherwise

        function _checkIfTaskIsDue(description, invokeTime){
            // set default value of lastrun to 0
            description.lastrun = description.lastrun || 0;

            // check how long it has been since the last time
            // the task was executed
            var elapsedTime = invokeTime - description.lastrun;

            // return true if the elapsed time is greater than or
            // equal to the cron frequency 
            if(elapsedTime - description.frequency * 10>= 0){
                return true;
            }

            // return false otherwise
            return false;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: underscore or lodash ?

Comment: post correct function for a start. callback to forEach trails off without even closing parameters.